# HTML remove white spaces in table row

Tags: php, html, css

I have question about deleting white spaces in table cell...
i.e I have that table cell

```
+------------+
+testtesttest+
+            +
+            +
+------------+
```

but if I have many symbols in text, that all is good(i.e):

```
+-------------+
+aksjhdfgasjhd+
+asdfasdfafdgh+
+asdfasdfasdfa+
+-------------+
```

all text and table cells are generated by php code:

```
$table = "<table cellspacing='0' width='520' border='1' id='tbl_table'>";
    $counter = 0;
    $total = count($tabled_mani);
    if ( $total % 2 != 0 ) {
        $total += 1;
    }

    // loop through the array
    for ($i=0; $i < count($tabled_mani); $i++) {
        if ( $counter % 2 == 0 ) {
            // first column
            $table .= "<tr><td>" . "&#x25CF;&nbsp;".iconv("cp1257", "utf-8", $tabled_mani[$i]) . "</td>";
        } else  {
            // second column
            $table .= "<td>" . "&#x25CF;&nbsp;".iconv("cp1257", "utf-8", $tabled_mani[$i]) . "</td></tr>";
        }
        $counter++;
    }
$table .= "</table>";

echo $table;
```

so by this code I generate table with two columns in it and all content was dinamycally added from array.

So any advices?

P.S `line-height` was setted to 5px in css, also I tried to change `<td>` height to auto, and it also dosen't helped.
In output string or HTML I don't have whitespaces in table cols.

**Edit 1:**
[image]

Comment: It is not quite clear to me what you are looking for. Might it be `cellpadding="0"`?

Comment: @DaanMeijer I want to set cell height to content height... i.e if I have one or two line text I want that after last text symbol I don't have any spaces in cell

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify what you want with screenshots? I still don't quite understand what you want.

Comment: @DaanMeijer see my edit

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of trimming whitespaces? You don't seem to have the same issue in the following rows.

Comment: Have you used Chrome Inspector to see what element the white space belongs to?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem might be some HTML coming in from your input (maybe a whole bunch of `<p>` tags). Instead of `iconv("cp1257", "utf-8", $tabled_mani[$i])` try `strip_tags(iconv("cp1257", "utf-8", $tabled_mani[$i]))`.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to all. 
I was found answer... I just adde one more if check for string length and all is ok now!

Comment: being what exactly? that doesn't really qualify as an answer, IMHO.